# How do I test email to case in the Sandbox

Tags: sandbox, email2case

I activated the Email to Case On Demand and created a test email which I verified. all in the Sandbox. When I send an email to the test email address, it creates a case in our Production environment. How do I get this to push cases only to the Sandbox? Help!

Thanks,

Answer (score 11):

What Brian is trying to tell you is that there are **different** email addresses for Production and for Sandbox Email to Case. Cases are being created in Production because you are using a production email to case address. You need to actually create a completely different email to case address in your sandbox and use that one to test. Then when you go live in production, you will get a new one to use for production cases.

Most likely you have setup an on-demand email address and handed that off to your email admins to create a forward for. To test your email to case in your sandbox org, simply just send an email to the Email Service Address in your sandbox org. [image: Email Address]

Answer (score 9):

You will need to update the email forward for Email-to-Case to the new email when you setup the email address in Sandbox.

The addresses are different in the two environments. The test email is sent to your email address during setup. The email address you are forwarding to [your email prefix}@"".Case.Salesforce.com is the address that is creating the case.

Comment: Hi Brian, Sorry but how do I update the email address to create cases in the Sandbox? I share a license so do I just put the test email address in the shared user's email address? Or should I just deactivate a user and create a new user in the Sandbox for testing? Sorry for all the questions but I need the cases to go into the Sandbox.

Comment: Setup > Customize > Cases > Email to Case   I can post more detailed instructions if you need them.